# NHibernate Webapp With Multiple Databases Which SessionContext To Use

Tags: nhibernate, database-connection, sessionfactory

We use NHibernate with fluent configuration in our web application.

We have a single configuration database and a multitude of different databases holding customer data.

For each database we make a fluent configuration and a SessionFactory when it is first used.

We obtain sessions by calling the OpenSession method on it, and dispose it when we are through with it.

However sometimes we get an error message that the ADO data-reader is still active when we attempt to read. Indicating that NHibernate is trying to (re)use the same connection, something we are trying to avoid.

How can we make sure that our database requests are handled by a connection in an atomic fashion. (No re-use by other requests)

I guess that recreating the SessionFactory might work, but that seems expensive

Answer (score 2):

A few questions

- You are using different connection strings so it is separate application pools?
- What is the exact error message you get?

I can't see how this should be nHibernate's fault. If the problem is easily reproduceable then maybe you can try to:

- Trace from the database side to see whats going on (especially sp_resetconnection)
- Disable connection pooling to see if that makes a difference

Comment: @ Miracleforhire: We have different connection pools (on for each database, the default of ADO.Net.) The problem however occurs when during a series of web requests the central database is read. NHibernate gives out the same database connection to a new request before the previous one is finished. Some internal connection/session caching perhaps?. I want a "new" session (with a "clean" connection form the pool) each time I call SessionFactory.OpenSession().

Comment: Are you sure that it is the two different SessionFactory that causes the problems are you sure you are not using a single session in multiple threads ore something similar?

If you are convinced its hibernate messing it up look at the ConnectionProvider class in nHibernate and where its called in the source, its pretty straight forward.

Comment: All sessions for the central database are obtained from a single session factory. Do I need to recreate the session factory each time to make sure I don't get an in-use connection? The connection pool only gives out connections that are closed by the previous process so I don't think that's the problem.